# How to display a variable mantissa length

Tags: c#, string, label

I have a label on a form that displays a float (_DataFloat) with a variable (_Digits) that sets the number of digits to show to the right of the decimal point. Assuming that _Digits can be any value from 0 through 6, is there a better way of formatting the text other than using a switch statement as below?

```
switch (_Digits) {
    case 0:
        label1.Text = _DataFloat.ToString("0");
        break;
    case 1:
        label1.Text = _DataFloat.ToString("0.0");
        break;
    case 2:
        label1.Text = _DataFloat.ToString("0.00");
        break;
    case 3:
        label1.Text = _DataFloat.ToString("0.000");
        break;
    case 4:
        label1.Text = _DataFloat.ToString("0.0000");
        break;
    case 5:
        label1.Text = _DataFloat.ToString("0.00000");
        break;
    case 6:
        label1.Text = _DataFloat.ToString("0.000000");
        break;
    default:
        label1.Text = _DataFloat.ToString("0.00");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
var format = String.Format("0.{0}", new string('0', _Digits));
label1.Text = _DataFloat.ToString(format);
```